# How to print PNG chunk_type as text?

Tags: elixir

Here I am grabbing the chunk_type in 4 8bit parts and then printing the binary. But I would prefer to grab it in one 32bit part.

```
  defp read_chunks(<<>>), do: IO.puts "Done"
  defp read_chunks(<<
                  length :: size(32),
                  chunk_type1 :: size(8),
                  chunk_type2 :: size(8),
                  chunk_type3 :: size(8),
                  chunk_type4 :: size(8),
                  chunk_data :: binary - size(length),
                  _crc :: size(32),
                  chunks :: binary
                  >>) do
    IO.inspect <<chunk_type1,chunk_type2,chunk_type3,chunk_type4>>
    read_chunks(chunks)
  end
```

Like this

```
  defp read_chunks(<<>>), do: IO.puts "Done"
  defp read_chunks(<<
                  length :: size(32),
                  chunk_type :: size(32),
                  chunk_data :: binary - size(length),
                  _crc :: size(32),
                  chunks :: binary
                  >>) do
    IO.inspect ???
    read_chunks(chunks)
  end
```

How can I print out `chunk_type` in the second example so that it is readable text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same behavior as the first snippet, you need to read `chunk_type` as a `binary`.

Replace

```
chunk_type :: size(32),
```

with

```
chunk_type :: binary-size(4),
```

(`4` because `binary` requires the size in bytes, not bits.)

Comment: When I do that, the pattern doesn't match any more.

`** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in HideInImage.read_chunks/1`